# Ubuntu 16.04 Apache2 only requires password once?

Tags: .htaccess, apache2, ubuntu-16.04

I have a server running, and setup an htaccess file. Everything works and it does require a password to gain access to the folder I set, but once the password is used, it has never required verification again. Seems insecure, so I'm wondering how to require re-entering a password. Like some kind of time-out on the access, but I don't know what to look for, and all I've found is people trying to stop needing a password all the time.

Please help with either a solution, or point me in the right direction for what I need to be searching for.

I am using ssl, and .httaccess file with basic auth setup in the apache config file.

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Restricted Content"
  AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
  Require valid-user
</Directory>
```

Comment: That is because your cache is remembering your users when they log in. It will ask for them to log in again, but only on loading a new browser session. Really, you should have a proper User Login. `.htaccess` is not secure in the slightest and you should avoid using it for security measures. I'm not sure what setup you have, but I would be using PHP to do this, connecting it to a database and encrypting all passwords correctly. It is relatively simple to do and there are hundreds of tutorials online :)

Comment: Thanks @Lag, I did end up going this direction and building a full php login system. Works much better ad gives me full control of users. I just didn't think it would be as easy as it was. I followed this video [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xb8aad4MRx8), and then just made adjustments to customize it to my needs.

Comment: That's great Zach! It really is a much more efficient and secure way of dealing with Logins. `.htaccess` is great, but it really is a big security flaw, so shouldn't be used for things like that. I'm glad you got it all sorted :)

Answer (score 0):

As I know, apache/HTTP authentication don't gives you control.
After first authentication, your server cannot instruct the browser to logout or timeout. HTTP authentication does not work with session/cookies and the browser shall continually send authentication credentials. 
To logout you should close the browser.

looking in Apache webpage: `AuthDigestNonceLifetime` Directive could be useful the value is in seconds for the time. i use 300 here.

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    AuthType Digest
    AuthName "Restricted-Content"
    AuthDigestDomain "http://127.0.1.2"
    AuthDigestProvider file
    AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd         
    AuthDigestNonceLifetime 30          
    Require valid-user
</Directory>
```

Also you will have to use the `htdigest` command to generate the `.htpasswd` file

```
htdigest -c /etc/apache2/.htpasswd Restricted-Content username
```

then set the password
then set the `AuthDigestDomain` to your URL or IP

this conffiguration can only work with the degest based authentication. although the user must clear their browser cache manually.

but i would recommend you switch to a different method for autentication, unless its the only option for the application

Comment: I added that, but it caused an error when trying to restart. I'm guessing theres a conflict between usingAuthDigest, and SSL, or there's more to setting up the AuthDigest?

Comment: Hey @kishea, I tried this first, but it kept throwing an error with my config file. Maybe the version I'm running doesn't fully support it anymore, or there is a need to add more so it knows what's going on? In the end I went with building out a php based login system to do away with basic auth limitations anyway. Thank you for your answer though!